# Return a list of dict in regex instead of print

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I want to return a dict format when extracting log data from  a file that records the access a user makes when visiting a web page.
I dont have a probleme with the pattern i just want my fonction to return a dict file because all it does is showing the items

```py
def logs():
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
        pattern=r'(?P<host>\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)\s\W\s(?P<user_name>[a-zA-Z]+\d+|-)'
        for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata): 
            print(item.groupdict())
```

Comment: Do you mean a list of dictionaries? `dicts = []
for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata): 
  dicts.append(item.groupdict())`, https://ideone.com/Y4EZyI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your function to return a value, you need to use the `return` keyword:

```py
def logs():
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
        pattern=r'(?P<host>\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)\s\W\s(?P<user_name>[a-zA-Z]+\d+|-)'
        return [item.groupdict() for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata)]
```

Comment: Thank you that's the correct method but i used this instead

 a=list()
    for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata): 
       a.append(item.groupdict())
    return a